# Switching view when pressing list item in Side Panel

Tags: sencha-touch

I try to get started with Sencha Touch but I haven't quite figured out how to do things.
I'm using the [innofied SlideNav](http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/) for navigation.

Now I want to the change the view when you press on an item in the side panel. What would be the best way to do this (MVC)?.

I could use something like `Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('SlideNav.view.New'));` but that renders a whole new page.

TabPanels are maybe similar but they just list items and make the switching themselves.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a Card layout?  You could set your Viewport to have a container with a card layout, and then use `setActiveItem()` on that container.  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card

Comment: please make a fiddle, demo somewhere with what you've got. This will save other people's time putting those plugins and cases just to visualize the problem. Put some necessary code in question as well. You can try http://senchafiddle.com or http://jsfiddle.net for demos.